# Android: The meaning of the codes returned by GLUtils.getype and getInternalFormat

Tags: android, opengl-es

Where are the meanings the codes returned by GLUtils.getype and getInternalFormat listed?

Right now I am getting:

Internal Format: 6407 
Type: 33635

Code used to generate this is as follows:

```
Log.v("GLSurfaceView", "Internal Format "+GLUtils.getInternalFormat(mBitmap)+" Type: "+GLUtils.getType(mBitmap));
```

The formats and types which are available are listed here : http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You linked to the OpenGL spec, instead you should look at the [glTexImage2D in the OpenGL-ES spec](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glTexImage2D.xml).

The constants you need are defined in the [GL10](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html) class. Internal format 6407 is [GL10.GL_RGB](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html#GL_RGB) for example, and type 33635 is [GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html#GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5).